# Winsock timeout

Tags: c++, winsock

Здравствуйте. Возникла проблема при работе с Winsock - в частности, не могу выставить время таймаута коннекта. Читал, что это можно сделать, переведя его в неблокирующий режим и выставить нужный параметр через select(), но это не дало никаких результатов. Пытался сделать следующим образом

```
    timeval time_out;
time_out.tv_sec = 5;
time_out.tv_usec = 0; //5 sek
fd_set setW, setE;

FD_ZERO(&setW);
FD_SET(sock, &setW);
FD_ZERO(&setE);
FD_SET(sock, &setE);
int ierr1=12;
ierr1 = select(0, NULL, &setW, &setE, &time_out);
ierr1 = FD_ISSET(sock, &setW);
```

но при попытке законектится - сокет возвращает -1. В опциях самого винсока я не нашел настроек таймаута. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как быть?

Comment: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/125754-solved-winsock-connect-with-timeout/

Comment: @goldstar_labs проблема в том, что коннект все равно происходит в течение 20 секунд, а мне нужно выставить время ожидания соединения до коннекта.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А нет, я не прав. Конструкция помогла, но с одним нюансом. Прежде всего нужно было перевести сокет в неблокирующий режим. Вот такая конструкция решила мою проблему:

```
unsigned long nonblocking;
int status = ioctlsocket(sock, FIONBIO, &nonblocking);

int socket_status = ::connect(sock,(sockaddr *)&fpga_addr,sizeof(fpga_addr)) ;
if(socket_status == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    int iError = WSAGetLastError();
    if(iError == WSAEWOULDBLOCK)
    {
        fd_set Write, Err;

        TIMEVAL Timeout;
        int TimeoutSec = 4; // timeout after 10 seconds

        FD_ZERO(&Write);
        FD_ZERO(&Err);
        FD_SET(sock, &Write);
        FD_SET(sock, &Err);

        Timeout.tv_sec = TimeoutSec;
        Timeout.tv_usec = 0;

        int timeout_status = select(0,          //ignored
            NULL,       //read
            &Write, //Write Check
            &Err,       //Error Check
            &Timeout);
        if(timeout_status == 0)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            if(FD_ISSET(sock, &Write))
            {
                return sock;
            }
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Спасибо @goldstar_labs за наводку!

Comment: всегда пожалуйста, вы можете отметить свой ответ как правильный, чтобы закрыть вопрос)

Answer (score 0):

Использование неблокирующего сокета без надобности черезмерно. Посмотрите [setsockopt](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740476(v=vs.85).aspx) про флаг `SO_RCVTIMEO`. Тогда и при блокирующих input/output операциях будет использоваться тайм-аут.